# Como fazer dois Groupby seguidos no python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Bom dia.

Estou precisando fazer um groupby numa base de dados porém agrupando duas vezes (primeiro a coluna "Pedido Marketplace" e segundo a coluna "Tipo da Transação (e depois somar o valor). Só consigo fazer o groupby dos pedidos marketplace, porém preciso saber qual foi o tipo da transação de cada um e somar se houver mais de um tipo igual. Se alguem conseguir me ajudar, agradeço muito.
Obrigado.

[Print da Lógica desejada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iWVA.png)

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Parece que a sua pergunta contém alguns problemas. Nós não faremos o seu trabalho da faculdade ou lição de casa, mas se você estiver com dificuldade em alguma parte específica, compartilhe o seu código, diga o que já tentou fazer e qual está sendo a dificuldade, assim você aumenta as suas chances em conseguir uma boa resposta. Não deixe de ler o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/100416) para ter uma experiência melhor por aqui.

Comment: sobre a pergunta... acredito que basta vc passar mais de 1 coluna no [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)`( ['col_b', 'col_b'])`... e depois usar o [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) para fazer a soma

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde,

Conforme a [documentação do pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), pode passar uma lista dos valores para realizar o group by

DataFrame.groupby(by=None)

Parameters
by:mapping, function, label, or list of labels

Então, passa a lista das colunas que irão sofrer o group by com a função de soma, conforme abaixo:

```
df.groupby(['Pedido Marketplace','Tipo da Transação']).sum()
```

Exemplo do pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
    ("bird", "Falconiformes", 389.0),
    ("bird", "Psittaciformes", 24.0),
    ("mammal", "Carnivora", 80.2),
    ("mammal", "Primates", np.nan),
    ("mammal", "Carnivora", 58),
],
index=["falcon", "parrot", "lion", "monkey", "leopard"],
columns=("class", "order", "max_speed"),)

df.groupby(['class','order']).sum()
```

[imagem group by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB8Oc.png)